# Trying to avoid getClass() in Java

Tags: java, hibernate

I often read that using `getClass()` in Java is a sign of bad design.

So... I have a generic "DAO" abstract class for Hibernate where I have this method:

```
public List<T> findByDate(Class<T> clazz, Date date) { ... }
```

I use a generic "DAO" abstract class and the `clazz` parameter type for the method is `Class<T>`, this is a pretty common practice.

I should call `findByDate()` using something like:

```
myDao.findByDate(MyTable.class, date)
```

But here's the problem. I don't have a settled `MyTable` class, because that class is instantiated by a Factory (Factory design pattern), so I could have `MyTable1`, `MyTable2`, `MyTable3` etc.. Every class extends an abstract `MyAbstractTable` class so I tried:

```
myDao.findByDate(MyAbstractTable.class, date)
```

But at runtime it **doesn't** work. I think it doesn't work because I use Hibernate annotations inside my `MyTable1`, `MyTable2`, `MyTable3` etc. classes (where I specify my columns mapping for Hibernate), so I must use the specific classes.

So my solution would be to use something like:

```
MyAbstractTable table = TableFactory.getInstance().createTable(key);
```

and

```
myDao.findByDate(table.getClass(), date)
```

in order to get the type returned by the Factory... and it does work... but I'd have to use `getClass()` so I think I could be doing something wrong. Is the whole design flawed? Thank you.

Comment: You say your DAO is abstract... how is it instanciated?

Comment: Using another factory (DaoFactory).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I often read that using getClass() in Java is a sign of bad design.

This is the case for code like this:

```
if(foo.getClass() == MyClass.class) {....}
```

In your case, this is not the case :-)

However, I still don't understand why your abstract DAO can't have a field `private Class<T> klass` that is set by concrete subclasses/the constructor, which then gets used for determining the actual class to pass to find.

Comment: I went for the "private Class<T> klass" way :-) Still, I understand that in this case getClass() is acceptable. Thanks to everybody.

Answer (score 2):

That's like the `goto`-rules:

1. Avoid using `goto`
2. Avoid *always* avoiding using `goto`

What I want to say is, there are use cases where avoiding calling `getClass()` doesn't add to the readability and maintainability of your code.

PS: I haven't used `goto` for years, whereas I use `getClass()` quite a number of times in cases like the one you pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

Using `getClass` for deciding logic is definitely considered bad but in your scenario there is nothing wrong in creating and using such API.

```
myDao.findByDate(MyAbstractTable.class, date)
```

Note that I am using Class literal and not object reference to get the class object.

The reason probably it did not work is maybe because your implementation needs concrete class so that it can instantiate it and return you the object you are asking for. Obviously it cannot instantiate Abstract class.

There are several standard Java EE data access API's which use this kind of signature.
For e.g., the [JPA EntityManager API](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html) has following method

```
find(java.lang.Class<T> entityClass, java.lang.Object primaryKey)
```

So for getting the class I would not use the object reference, rather class literal to get the class object.

Comment: I edited my question because the casing was misleading, I actually used the Class literals.